# Uncaught Error: Template was precompiled with an older version of Handlebars

Tags: templates, ember.js, handlebars.js, bower, grunt-ember-templates

I'm using Bower to manage my frontend dependencies and `grunt-ember-templates` to precompile handlebars templates.

These are the dependencies in `bower.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "ember": "~1.3.1",
  "jquery": "~2.0.3",
  "normalize-css": "~2.1.3",
  "jquery.cookie": "~1.4.0",
  "font-awesome": "~4.0.3"
}
```

... and in `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "bower": "~1.2.8",
  "grunt": "~0.4.2",
  "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5.0",
  "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
  "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
  "handlebars": "~1.3.0",
  "ember-template-compiler": "~1.4.0-beta.1",
  "grunt-ember-templates": "~0.4.18"
},
```

However, when I compile and run my Ember application I get this error:

`Assertion failed: Ember Handlebars requires Handlebars version 1.0 or 1.1, COMPILER_REVISION expected: 4, got: 5 - Please note: Builds of master may have other COMPILER_REVISION values.`

`Uncaught Error: Template was precompiled with an older version of Handlebars than the current runtime. Please update your precompiler to a newer version (>= 2.0.0) or downgrade your runtime to an older version (<= 1.0.rc.2).`

And these are the versions:

```
> Ember.VERSION
> "1.3.2"
> Handlebars.VERSION
> "v2.0.0-alpha.1"
```

As you see `handlebars` is not mentioned explicitly as a dependency, but is rather resolved through Ember. But somehow it resolves to a newer (incompatible) version.

How do I fix the version of `handlebars`?

Comment: Why do you have ember, jquery etc under devDependencies? should probably be under dependencies. For node packages dev dependencies is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `bower install handlebars#1.3.0 --save`, but yes this is a issue with bower. I saw you created https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/1114