# Template was precompiled with an older version of Handlebars than the current runtime

Tags: gulp, handlebars.js

I have this error, but the different between [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722230/uncaught-error-template-was-precompiled-with-an-older-version-of-handlebars) and my question is that I'm using gulp instead grunt.

First, my handlebar runtime is *handlebars v4.0.5* (js file).

The output of *handlebar -v* is 4.0.5

This is my **gulpfile.js**:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var handlebars = require('gulp-handlebars');
var wrap = require('gulp-wrap');
var declare = require('gulp-declare');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('default', ['templates','scripts'], function () {

});

gulp.task('templates', function () {
    gulp.src('templates/*.hbs')
      .pipe(handlebars())
      .pipe(wrap('Handlebars.template(<%= contents %>)'))
      .pipe(declare({
          namespace: 'MyApp.templates',
          noRedeclare: true, // Avoid duplicate declarations
      }))
      .pipe(concat('templates.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('js/dist'));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src([
     'bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.runtime.js',
     'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
     'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.js',    
     'js/dist/templates.js',
     'js/main.js'])
      .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('js/dist/'));
});
```

**Main.js**

```
"use strict";
var data = { title: 'This Form', name: 'Joey' };
var html = MyApp.templates.hellotemplate(data);
// console.log(html);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dynamic-content').html(html);
});
```

Where can be my problem?

**Error:**

> Uncaught Error: Template was precompiled with an older version of
>   Handlebars than the current runtime. Please update your precompiler to
>   a newer version (>= 4.0.0) or downgrade your runtime to an older
>   version (>= 2.0.0-beta.1).

I have precompiled the templates using *gulp* command.

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a better way to compile a template using a specific version of handlebars which is covered in the README: https://github.com/lazd/gulp-handlebars#compiling-using-a-specific-handlebars-version

Make sure you've specified the handlebars version in your app's `package.json` file:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "handlebars": "^4.0.5"
  }
}
```

Then require handlebars by passing it as a gulp-handlebars option in your gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('templates', function () {
  gulp.src('templates/*.hbs')
    .pipe(handlebars({
      handlebars: require('handlebars')
    }))
    .pipe(wrap('Handlebars.template(<%= contents %>)'))
    .pipe(declare({
      namespace: 'MyApp.templates',
      noRedeclare: true, // Avoid duplicate declarations
    }))
    .pipe(concat('templates.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js/dist'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my problem was in the *gulp-handlebars* package, because in the package loader, it is loading a minor version.

I update it manually and I solved my problem. Go to *node_modules* folder, find **gulp-handlebars** folder, open *package.json*, and update the dependicies like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.4",
    "handlebars": "4.0.5",
    "through2": "^0.6.3"
  }
```

Comment: I suggest using @Griffin answer, because if you would run `npm update` in this case the dependency would probably change.