# Getting template was precompiled with a newer version of Handlebars error with my Node.JS app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to create a Node.JS app that uses the open source Alpaca Forms package:

http://www.alpacajs.org/

I'm using Node version: **v0.10.25**

When I run the test page from the tutorial:

http://www.alpacajs.org/tutorial.html

Using the second sample page found in that tutorial:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link type="text/css" href="//code.cloudcms.com/alpaca/1.5.17/bootstrap/alpaca.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.3/handlebars.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.cloudcms.com/alpaca/1.5.17/bootstrap/alpaca.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="form"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#form").alpaca({
                    "schema": {
                        "title":"User Feedback",
                        "description":"What do you think about Alpaca?",
                        "type":"object",
                        "properties": {
                            "name": {
                                "type":"string",
                                "title":"Name"
                            },
                            "feedback": {
                                "type":"string",
                                "title":"Feedback"
                            },
                            "ranking": {
                                "type":"string",
                                "title":"Ranking",
                                "enum":['excellent','ok','so so']
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get the following two errors in the Chrome Debugger console, complaining that the templates I am using were compiled with a **newer** version of Handlebars than the current run-time, not *older* like most of the reported problems on SO specify.  Here is the error dump from the Chrome Debugger console:

```
Uncaught Error: Template was precompiled with a newer version of Handlebars than the current runtime. 
Please update your runtime to a newer version (>= 4.0.0).
    Exception @ handlebars.js:2520
    checkRevision @ handlebars.js:2693
    template @ handlebars.js:2709
    hb.template @ handlebars.js:196
    (anonymous function) @ alpaca.min.js:1
    (anonymous function) @ alpaca.min.js:1
    (anonymous function) @ alpaca.min.js:1

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).alpaca is not a function
    (anonymous function) @ (index):14
    j @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    k.fireWith @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    m.extend.ready @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
    J @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
```

I checked with NPM and I **am** using a version of Handlebars that is newer than 4.0.0:

```
$ npm ls | grep handlebars
└─┬ handlebars@4.0.5
```

So it appears the error message is *wrong*?

I found these two related SO posts:

[Template was precompiled with an older version of Handlebars than the current runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34854010/template-was-precompiled-with-an-older-version-of-handlebars-than-the-current-ru)

[Uncaught Error: Template was precompiled with an older version of Handlebars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21722230/uncaught-error-template-was-precompiled-with-an-older-version-of-handlebars)

But I am not using Gulp or Ember.JS so I don't know if the remedies given apply to my situation.

Here is a list of the packages I have installed according to NPM:

```
npm ls
/home/roschler
├─┬ express@4.13.4
│ ├─┬ accepts@1.2.13
│ │ ├─┬ mime-types@2.1.10
│ │ │ └── mime-db@1.22.0
│ │ └── negotiator@0.5.3
│ ├── array-flatten@1.1.1
│ ├── content-disposition@0.5.1
│ ├── content-type@1.0.1
│ ├── cookie@0.1.5
│ ├── cookie-signature@1.0.6
│ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ ├── depd@1.1.0
│ ├── escape-html@1.0.3
│ ├── etag@1.7.0
│ ├─┬ finalhandler@0.4.1
│ │ └── unpipe@1.0.0
│ ├── fresh@0.3.0
│ ├── merge-descriptors@1.0.1
│ ├── methods@1.1.2
│ ├─┬ on-finished@2.3.0
│ │ └── ee-first@1.1.1
│ ├── parseurl@1.3.1
│ ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.7
│ ├─┬ proxy-addr@1.0.10
│ │ ├── forwarded@0.1.0
│ │ └── ipaddr.js@1.0.5
│ ├── qs@4.0.0
│ ├── range-parser@1.0.3
│ ├─┬ send@0.13.1
│ │ ├── destroy@1.0.4
│ │ ├─┬ http-errors@1.3.1
│ │ │ └── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ ├── mime@1.3.4
│ │ ├── ms@0.7.1
│ │ └── statuses@1.2.1
│ ├── serve-static@1.10.2
│ ├─┬ type-is@1.6.12
│ │ ├── media-typer@0.3.0
│ │ └─┬ mime-types@2.1.10
│ │   └── mime-db@1.22.0
│ ├── utils-merge@1.0.0
│ └── vary@1.0.1
└─┬ handlebars@4.0.5
  ├── async@1.5.2
  ├─┬ optimist@0.6.1
  │ ├── minimist@0.0.10
  │ └── wordwrap@0.0.3
  ├─┬ source-map@0.4.4
  │ └── amdefine@1.0.0
  └─┬ uglify-js@2.6.2
    ├── async@0.2.10
    ├── source-map@0.5.3
    ├── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
    └─┬ yargs@3.10.0
      ├── camelcase@1.2.1
      ├─┬ cliui@2.1.0
      │ ├─┬ center-align@0.1.3
      │ │ ├─┬ align-text@0.1.4
      │ │ │ ├─┬ kind-of@3.0.2
      │ │ │ │ └── is-buffer@1.1.3
      │ │ │ ├── longest@1.0.1
      │ │ │ └── repeat-string@1.5.4
      │ │ └── lazy-cache@1.0.3
      │ ├─┬ right-align@0.1.3
      │ │ └─┬ align-text@0.1.4
      │ │   ├─┬ kind-of@3.0.2
      │ │   │ └── is-buffer@1.1.3
      │ │   ├── longest@1.0.1
      │ │   └── repeat-string@1.5.4
      │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
      ├── decamelize@1.2.0
      └── window-size@0.1.0
```

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: @Omarjmh I'm using v0.10.25

Comment: @Omarjmh Drop down?  The error message is saying I need a newer version of handlebars, not older.

Comment: @Omarjmh Just added my package list.

Comment: you need to either update your runtime, or lower handlebars

Comment: @Omarjmh Which runtime and to what version?  Also, what version of handlebars would get things working?

Comment: @Omarjmh Just tried that.  Package list (npm ls)  now shows: handlebars@3.0.0   Then I restarted Node.JS.  Still have the problem.

Comment: you need to read this blog post: http://berzniz.com/post/24743062344/handling-handlebarsjs-like-a-pro

Lets delete some of these comments, the thread is getting too long, I'm pretty sure I'm right about the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the example HTML, the Handlebars library being included via a script tag needs to be updated. When it refers to the runtime one, you need to **update the JS library you are explictly including and not the NPM package** (usually).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.3/handlebars.js"></script>
```

Should actually include one with version 4.0.0+. For example

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank!  That did it.  It works now.  By the way, during the (re)-install of handlebars 4.0.5 using NPM I got the following warnings.  Should I worry about them? [ WARNING 1] npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/is-buffer
npm WARN engine is-buffer@1.1.3: wanted: {"node":">=0.12"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.10"})[ WARNING 2] 
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lazy-cache
npm WARN engine is-buffer@1.1.3: wanted: {"node":">=0.12"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.25","npm":"1.3.10"})

Comment: No problem. And generally these collisions don't cause problems in my experience. You should be fine with ignoring them (so long as all works well with them of course). If you find an unusual issue with the building of handlebars, then maybe researching them would be a starting point. But I never tend to worry about these types of clashes - get them all the time. I tend to use node version >=0.12 though, as it seems to clean up things like this.